# Using ratchet and web sockets in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, sockets, laravel, laravel-5.1, ratchet

I'm implementing a chat inside my app, and I already got it to work locally using ratchet and websockets, but I have three doubts.

- In order for getting it to work I need to run my server created in this script:

  ```
  <?php require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

  use Subway\Http\Controllers\ChatController;
  use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
  use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
  use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

  $server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer(new ChatController)), 3000);

  $server->run();
  ```

  so in my terminal I need to run: `php bin/server.php` in order to make it work correctly. The thing is, is there a way in Laravel to start that php script when I start laravel service with `php artisan serve`?
- The other doubt is that I used the local ip "127.0.0.1" just for testing purposes, but, when I get it to the server, which ip should I use?
- For another test, I changed the local ip for my real ip which is "192.168.1.31", and a partner inside the same network, tested the chat, and we had communication with each other, but, when he gets to another section of the webpage, I automatically get disconnected, and the terminal stops running the server.php script, what could you tell me about the solution to this?

If Ratchet won't work for this implementation, I would be greatful if you could tell me how to use "Pusher" service inside laravel 5.1.

Thanks!

Comment: If you'd like to invest $4, Jeffery Way's tutorials are epic. https://laracasts.com/lessons/pusher-awesomeness. Also, you can check Broadcasting with Laravel.

Comment: Yeah, I started to use Pusher instead, it's so easy, thanks!